# How i can change the size of jscroll pane that is the parent of a jtable java

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NslfF.jpg)Regards colleagues 
I have a tough problems that I don't  found solution and I need help. I was working in a java project and I used a jtable to show data from a database so far so good, My project show the datas,but the problem is when i show many rows in the jtable, the size of the jscroll pane is small to show all rows and  only show some rows. I need know how i can change the size of the jscroll pane that is parent of the jtable that show the datas  .

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```js
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JScrollBar bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
bar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 0));
```

Comment: I tried it but this chave the size of the JScrollBar and i need chage the size of the area to show datas to the JScrollPane

Answer (score 0):

JScroolPane auto resizing.You can change your JFrame height size and also you can increase object array in first initialization if you not use Vector, it make the table show more rows even is empty.